# Find the derivative of $y = \frac{\sqrt[3]{4x^3+8}}{(x+2)^5}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can anyone solve 1b?

> 1. Find the derivatives of each of these functions.
>      b. $y = \frac{\sqrt[3]{4x^3+8}}{(x+2)^5}$

I am really confused, I used the quotient rule for differentiation of the chain rule and keep getting stuck.After the
$y′=\frac{f′(x)g(x)−g′(x)f(x)}{g(x)^2}$.

so far this is what I have done

[image]

Comment: And also do not send duplicate questions